# Sitecore Insert rules to ensure at most (1) children of a certain type

Tags: c#, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

Is there way in sitecore to ensure that a certain type of item can only have 1 child of a certain type of item? I'm reading the rules engine cookbook, but I'm not getting much details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the sites I worked on had a requirement that no more than 6 child items could exist below a certain item type. We considered using an insert option rule, but decided to abandon the idea because it did not prevent copying, moving, or duplicating items.

Instead we decided to extend the `item:created` event with a handler specifically for this task. Below is a stripped-down example of how it works. One obvious improvement would be to fetch the maximum child limit from a field on the parent item (visible to administrators only, of course). You could probably even leverage the rules engine here as well...

```
public void OnItemCreated(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var createdArgs = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as ItemCreatedEventArgs;

    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsNotNull(createdArgs, "args");
    if (createdArgs != null)
    {
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsNotNull(createdArgs.Item, "item");
        if (createdArgs.Item != null)
        {
            var item = createdArgs.Item;

            // NOTE: you may want to do additional tests here to ensure that the item
            // descends from /sitecore/content/home
            if (item.Parent != null && 
                item.Parent.TemplateName == "Your Template" &&
                item.Parent.Children.Count() > 6)
            {
                // Delete the item, warn user
                SheerResponse.Alert(
                    String.Format("Sorry, you cannot add more than 6 items to {0}.",
                                      item.Parent.Name), new string[0]);
                item.Delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full details? I'm new to sitecore, and I'm not completely sure where to start.... where does this event handler go?

Comment: Here's an [article on Sitecore events](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/API/Using%20Events.aspx). It's old, but most of it is still relevant. Basically, you would have to add reference to this class in the web.config under the sitecore/events section and it will get executed every time an item is created.

Comment: Also, here is an example reference: `<handler type="Your.Namespace.OnItemCreated, Your.Library" method="OnItemCreated"/>`

Comment: @DerekHunziker - This is a great solution! From your response, I inferred that the `item:created` event is raised when and item is moved, duplicated, copied, or created. Is this correct?

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel, I believe duplication and copying eventually bubble up to item:created at some point in the pipeline since a new item is being created. Moving does not, however, there is a separate event (item:moving) you can subscribe to for that.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel, Also, in the case of item:moving, you wouldn't want to "delete" the current item. Rather, you would simply want to abort the pipeline so that the move doesn't happen.